# Java. Convert string stream to other type

Tags: javafx, stream

I have class

```
public class ListItem {
    private final String text;
    private final BooleanProperty isSelected = new SimpleBooleanProperty();

    public BooleanProperty selectedProperty() {
        return isSelected ;
    }

    public final boolean isSelected() {
        return selectedProperty().get();
    }

    public final void setSelected(boolean isSelected) {
        selectedProperty().set(isSelected);
    }

    public ListItem(String text) {
        this.text = text ;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return getText(); 
    }
}
```

in other class I have this

```
private ObservableList<ListItem> ListData = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
```

some where in code i do this:

```
Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get(FILENAME), Charset.forName("windows-1251") );     
ListData = stream
  .filter(line -> line.startsWith("File"))
  .map(line -> line.substring(line.indexOf("=") + 1, line.length()))
  .collect(Collectors.toCollection(????));
```

What I must write in ???? position for convert string stream values to ListItem values? This convertion is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you've already created the `ObservableList`, you could simply use `forEach` to add every item to `ListData`. Furthermore you need to use the constructor of `ListItem` to wrap every element of the stream in a `ListItem`:

```
stream
      .filter(line -> line.startsWith("File"))
      .map(line -> line.substring(line.indexOf("=") + 1)) // there's also a version of substring that only takes the start index
      .map(ListItem::new) // equivalent to .map(line -> new ListItem(line))
      .forEach(ListData::add);
```

In case the list may not be empty this needs to be preceeded by `ListData.clear();`.

Answer (score 0):

The `collectionFactory` parameter of `Collectors.toCollection()` creates a `Collection`, which then has `add()` called on it for each member of the stream.

You need to convert the Strings in your stream to `ListItem`s -- use another `map` for this, then you can just use `Collectors.toList()`.

Comment: Thanks. just change code like this
ListData = stream
  .filter(line -> line.startsWith("File"))
  .map(line -> line.substring(line.indexOf("=") + 1, line.length()))
  .map(ListItem::new)
  .collect(Collectors.toCollection(FXCollections::observableArrayList));

Correct?